# C++ code crashes when I try to access the string member of a global object

Tags: arm, g++, threadx

I am running this program on a resource constrained ARM based ThreadX platform. The code is built using GCC g++ compiler. I am seeing a weird crash that I would like to understand more.

I have a class that has a member that is a string. I see that the program crashes when I make the object global(Case 1 below). It crashes in the print statement where I try to find the length of the string object. But, when I create a local object(Case 2 below), the program does not crash. When I create an object using 'new' it does not crash(case 3). I have rough idea of what might be going wrong(constructor invocation not taking place? Global objects are tricky etc.). I would like to understand what might be going wrong under the hood.

```
class A
{

    public:
        void printS()
        {
            printf(" string sz = %d \r\n", s.size());
        };
        string s;

};
```

Case 1:

```
A a;
void main()
{
    /* crashes inside the function prints while accessing the string s */
    a.printS();
}
```

Case 2:

```
void main()
{
    A a;  
    a.printS(); //works
}
```

Case 3:

```
A* a;
void main()
{   a = new A();
    a->printS(); //works
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like static object constructors are not called. Perhaps, the problem is in the linker script. Check if it contains lines for condtructors (`.init_array` section).

Answer (score 0):

Both cases work you just made a typo.

```
print instead of **printf**
```

Comment: Sorry. that was a typo. Corrected it. That is not the root cause.

Comment: I tested on codeblocks to be sure :/ MinGW gcc.... can you show me the error you get?

Comment: Thanks. No error reported. This is an embedded system running threadx RTOS. I dont have any JTAG debugger support.

Comment: Well, without debugger it's kind of shooting in the dark. Butt the only thing I can think of is that the global A a; is not permitted by software since MingCW has no issues. Try asking their support for help?